# For all ideals $I_1,I_2$, if $S^{-1}I_1 = S^{-1}I_2$ (localizations) then $I_1 = I_2$?

Tags: ring-theory

The [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring) says that the above implication holds if the ideals are prime. Here the multiplicative set $S$ contains $1$ but not $0$ and we are on a commutative ring $A$.

What can we say about the implication? And when the case is for prime ideals, how do I prove the implication?

Note that as commented below, we assume that $I_1, I_2$ are proper ideals.

Comment: This holds assumung $I_j\cap S=\emptyset$. If $s\in I\cap S$ , then $S^{-1}I=S^{-1}A$, aince it is an ideal containing a unit.